# Synchronize of ScheduledFuture.cancel() method

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, synchronized, scheduledexecutorservice

[Code below](http://media.pragprog.com/titles/vspcon/code/tamingSharedMutability/enhanceconcurrency/EnergySource.java) is cutted example from ["Programming Concurrency on the JVM: Mastering Synchronization, STM, and Actors" book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/193435676X)

I don't understand why author synchronizing **stopEnergySource** method, which just cancels ScheduledFuture task, which represented by **replenishTask** variable? There are no other methods that use this variable. 
Is it desirable practice to synchronize Future.cancel calls or it just needed for ScheduledFuture?

```
public class EnergySource {
  //...
  private static final ScheduledExecutorService replenishTimer =
    Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(10);
  private ScheduledFuture<?> replenishTask;

  private EnergySource() {}

  private void init() {   
    replenishTask = replenishTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
      public void run() { replenish(); }
    }, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }

  public static EnergySource create() {
    final EnergySource energySource = new EnergySource();
    energySource.init();
    return energySource;
  }

  public long getUnitsAvailable() { 
    //...
  }

  public long getUsageCount() { 
    //...
  }

  public boolean useEnergy(final long units) {
    //...
  }

  public synchronized void stopEnergySource() { // what for **synchronized** is?
    replenishTask.cancel(false); 
  }

  private void replenish() { 
    //...
  }
}
```

Comment: That does not make much sense...

Comment: The `ScheduledFuture` does not need that `synchronized` keyword. Even worse, if that’s the only `synchronized` code inside that class, that synchronization has no effect which makes it even more misleading.

Comment: After looking at the full code, I can tell you that the usage of `AtomicLong` inside the `replenish()` method is also broken (“check-then-act” anti-pattern).

Comment: This is not very good code... I'd say it is a mistake.

Comment: So `Future.cancel()` do not need to be synchronized at all, or it depends?

Comment: Any feedback on my answer?

Answer (score 0):

> There are no other methods that use this variable. Is it desirable practice to synchronize Future.cancel calls or it just needed for ScheduledFuture?

I believe that the author of the code is trying to force memory barriers in case a different thread is trying to call `stopEnergySource()` that started the job in the first place.

However, if this was the case then the `init()` method should *also* be `synchronized` because they are not doing a safe publishing of the `replenishTask` field.  That field is not `final` and the compiler is allowed to have `create(...)` return but continue the construction and initialization of the `EnergySource` object a later.

If multiple threads were creating and stopping these objects, you could easily get a NPE in `stopEnergySource(...)`, even with the `synchronized` keyword on it.